# How can I expose a custom port on k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

The script I want to deploy listens to `:4123` and k8s probably expose only `:80` by default. How can I expose `:4123` such that my script will be able to accept requests?

I tried port forwarding but there's a permission error to forward `:80` to `:4123` and k8s didn't allow to deploy an image that listens to `:80` (since it's probably busy already).

Comment: That's a lot of "probably".  Can you provide a [mcve] showing what specifically you're running, how you've configured your pod/service, and what issues you're encountering?

Comment: Is port 80 a nginx-ingress? If yes. create an ingress which points to your service which listens on port 4123 or else you can simply expose your pod as Node port service.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which port to use locally, so you can just choose that the local port `8888` will be forwarded to the port `4123` in your container

```
kubectl port-forward your-pod 8888:4123
```

You can use `8888` or any other free port on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by @fiunchinho, local port forwarding might help in your case. Adding `--address 0.0.0.0` to this command makes it avaiable for all your interfaces like below:

```
$ kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 nginx-55bd7c9fd-6fpnx 8888:80
```

You can also expose it via External LoadBalancer like below:

```
kubectl expose <your-deploy> --port 80 --target-port 4123 --type LoadBalancer
```

Note: You need to have cloud provider in order to use `type: LoadBalancer`. For more info check [Cloud providers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) in the Kubernetes documentation.

See Kubernetes documentation for more details:

[Forward a local port to a port on the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

[Exposing an External IP Address to Access an Application in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)